# change the route url on clicking the button

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to navigate the page through clicking the span so far its working fine for me this code. But just wanted to know is this  only way to achieve this or is there any possible to handle within one function instead having twice functions and two using Output event emitter? Please suggest.

**Parent component:**

```
public navigateAbout() {
    this.router.navigateUrl('/about');
}
public navigateContact() {
    this.router.navigateUrl('/contact');
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
@Output() public navigateAbout = new EventEmitter<void>();
@Output() public navigateContact = new EventEmitter<void>();


public navigateAboutPage():void {
    this.navigateAbout.emit();
}

public navigateContactPage():void {
    this.navigateContact.emit();
}
```

**Child Template:**

```
<ol>
<li>...... <span (click)="navigateAboutPage()">about</span>......</li>
<li>...... <span (click)="navigateContactPage()">contact</span>......</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me know if this helps.

```
<ol>
<li>...... <span (click)="navigate('about')">about</span>......</li>
<li>...... <span (click)="navigate('contact')">contact</span>......</li>
</ol>
```

template

```
navigate(path){
    this.router.navigate([path])
  }
```